# A probability problem involving probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am going through a probability book where the following has been claimed :

If $$f_{X}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{U}(x-y)f_{V}(y)dy$$

then $f_{X}=f_{U}*f_{V}$

where $X, U, V$ are continuous random variables where $U$ and $V$ are independent.

I don't understand this argument.

Comment: I believe the right side of your equation is the definition of $f_U * f_V$.

Comment: If you forget for a second about random variables, you obtain a definition of [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

Comment: In addition to the comments above, note that $f_U\star f_V$ where $U$ and $V$ are independent random variables is the density of $U+V$.

Comment: prasenjit: What about beginning to accept some answers to your 63 questions on the site?

Comment: understood. Initially, I thought $*$ as multiplication. That created the whole confusion. Thanks all for clearing the doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the probability density of $X=U+V$, which is given by the convolution of the PDFs of $U$ and $V$. So it's just the definition of convolution, for which the symbol '$*$' is used. Addition of independent RVs corresponds to the convolution of their PDFs.